# How to inherit ACL's/permissions automatically when creating new folder using Finder?

Tags: finder, permission, smb

We are using an Iomega file storage which is connected to our network. Our Windows Domain Controller is creating a share to this file storage, so our Windows users can easily access the share using \domaincontroller\share

When those users create a new folder, the file/directory permissions are inherited from the parent's folder. Everybody can read/write in their newly created folders, which is perfect.

When a Mac user (which is directly accessing the file storage) is creating a new folder, special permissions (read/write for current user) are applied and no else can write files in this newly created folder. The only way to solve this, is to RDP to a Windows console and reset the ACL's.

What's the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Our Storage is writing the ACLs automatically for the OS X Clients by simply setting the owner/group to "admin:administrators". The ACLs are controlled via an AD. That works for us and all folders have the right permissions automatically.

Comment: Can you tell me where in AD you configure this? Seems exactly what we need

Comment: Btw, we are using an old Windows 2003 server (SBS)

Comment: You said "directly accessing." What does that mean, e.g. connection protocol, storage format, etc.?  @YoshiBotX Learning AD at the moment.  I'd love to learn how to control ACL's via AD. :)

Comment: I mean: Finder > CMD + K > SMB://#NAME_OF_MY_FS

Answer (score 1):

[By default,](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785913%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Active Directory objects inherit ACEs from the security descriptor located in their parent container object. Inheritance enables the access control information defined at a container object in Active Directory to apply to the security descriptors of any subordinate objects, including other containers and their objects. This eliminates the need to apply permissions each time a child object is created.

If necessary, you can change the inherited permissions. However, as a best practice, avoid changing the default permissions or inheritance settings on Active Directory objects. For more information, see [Best practices for assigning permissions on Active Directory objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786285%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [Changing inherited permissions.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758122%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but then I have to inherit the permissions each time manually, when I create a new folder? I want this process to be automized ...